# Create a .csv file in every folder using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a directory with about 600 folders. In every each folder I need to create a .csv file and have 2 predefined values inside (valueA and valueB). I managed to do that by writing:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory | 
ForEach-Object {
  New-Item -ItemType file -Path "$($_.FullName)" -Name "$($_.Name).csv
}
```

It works great, however I would like to have this files .csv files created with 2 values already inside: valueA and valueB as I mentioned above. Any suggestions how can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you saying you want to overwrite the values? Can you be a bit clearer

Comment: Hi Isaac, there is nothing to overwrite. I'm creating empty .csv files, but I would like to have 2 rows already inside instead. One row would be called "ValueA" and second one "ValueB". Hopefully I have explained it a little bit better.

Comment: do you want to make the header line for two columns OR two 1-item rows with no header line?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want two **columns** created, not **rows**.

Try

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory |
ForEach-Object { 
    $out = Join-Path -Path $_.FullName -ChildPath  ('{0}.csv' -f $_.Name)
    "" | Select-Object ValueA, ValueB | 
    Export-Csv -Path $out -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Hope this helps